# Python - object attribute assignment fails

Tags: python

**My question is**, after this line:  `-> self.__serverUrl = serverUrl`

Why is this the case?:
`*** AttributeError: Client instance has no attribute '__serverUrl'`

**Details**

I'm using Beatbox to interact with Salesforce and I was getting an error

`*** AttributeError: Client instance has no attribute '_Client__serverUrl'`

I wondered why this field was being accessed before it was set, so I added `pdb.set_trace()` thinking I could find some answers.  This is what I saw (note line 67):

```
(Pdb)
--Call--
> /app/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beatbox/_beatbox.py(65)useSession()
-> def useSession(self, sessionId, serverUrl):
(Pdb) l
 64         # initialize from an existing sessionId & serverUrl, useful if we're being launched via a custom link
 65  ->     def useSession(self, sessionId, serverUrl):
 66             self.sessionId = sessionId
 67             self.__serverUrl = serverUrl
 68             (scheme, host, path, params, query, frag) = urlparse(self.__serverUrl)
 69             self.__conn = makeConnection(scheme, host)
 70
```

I check the value of serverUrl, and all is as it should be.  Then I get to line 67, let it execute and think that the value of `serverUrl` would be in `self.__serverUrl`.  Apparently not....

```
> /app/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beatbox/_beatbox.py(67)useSession()
-> self.__serverUrl = serverUrl
(Pdb) n
> /app/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beatbox/_beatbox.py(68)useSession()
-> (scheme, host, path, params, query, frag) = urlparse(self.__serverUrl)
(Pdb) self.__serverUrl
*** AttributeError: Client instance has no attribute '__serverUrl'
```

What is happening here!? This shouldn't be happening.  It looks like the assignment is just quietly failing.  Why is this value not being assigned here?

**The Source**

The source code I'm working with is [here](http://code.google.com/p/salesforce-beatbox/source/browse/)

I create a beatbox client and login

```
svc = PythonClient()
svc.login(username, password)
```

This calls the login method of python_client.Client.  python_client.Client.login calls the login method of it's superclass _beatbox.Client, which looks like this:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, serverUrl=None):
       ...

    # login, the serverUrl and sessionId are automatically handled, returns the loginResult structure       
    def login(self, username, password):
        lr = LoginRequest(self.serverUrl, username, password).post()
        self.useSession(str(lr[_tPartnerNS.sessionId]), str(lr[_tPartnerNS.serverUrl]))
        return lr

    # initialize from an existing sessionId & serverUrl, useful if we're being launched via a custom link   
    def useSession(self, sessionId, serverUrl):
        self.sessionId = sessionId
        self.__serverUrl = serverUrl
        (scheme, host, path, params, query, frag) = urlparse(self.__serverUrl)
        self.__conn = makeConnection(scheme, host)
```

The assginment happens in _beatbox.Client.useSession, which is the superclass of the object `svc`

Comment: which is it?  is it '_Client__serverUrl' or `__serverUrl`?  You might be a victim of name mangling ...

Comment: Outside of this method, it's _Client_serverUrl, inside the method it's _serverUrl.  Name mangling doesn't happen inside class methods does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Names prefixed by a double underscore (and not suffixed by a double underscore) are *mangled* when they appear within a class scope. The names are mangled by prefixing `_<classname>`.

If you declare a function at global scope which sets a double-underscore-prefixed name, you will set the wrong attribute because the name mangling will not occur. If you declare such a function in a derived class, you will also access the wrong attribute because the name mangling will add the derived class's name instead of the base class (hence, name mangling implements a weak form of private attributes).

The proper thing to do would be to avoid name mangling altogether if subclasses need to access the attribute, or use a property. If you can't avoid it, you will have to use this kludge:

```
self._Client__serverUrl = ...
```